# Como cerrar la conexion correctamente con MySQL en Java al leer desde la base de datos para llenar un JTable

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

Yo solicito en mi programa un Numero teléfono de origen, otro de destino y la duración. Lo guardo en la base de datos, luego debo leer la base de datos para llenar un JTable pero, me esta dando el siguiente error:

> mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>       No operations allowed after connection closed.

Estoy cerrando las conexiones de manera incorrecta?, qué me hace falta?.

Este es mi código:

```
// Agregar filas al JTable leyendo la base de datos
Connection conn = conexion.getConnection();
Statement st;

// Creamos un objeto de la clase ResultSet,
// la cual será la encargada de devolvernos los resultados de los registros
ResultSet rs;

// Crear sentencia SQL para seleccionar/obtener en la base de datos
String showTableSQL = "SELECT * FROM llamadas";

                try {
                    // Establecemos la comunicación entre nuestra aplicación java y la base de datos
                    st = conn.createStatement();

                    // Le pasamos al objeto de ResultSet el resultado de ejecutar la sentencia "query"
                    // Con "executeQuery" realizamos una consulta a la base de datos
                    rs = st.executeQuery(showTableSQL);

                    // En este bucle vamos recorriendo valores mientras existan
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        // Obtenemos el modelo del JTable
                        model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

                        // Agregamos las filas al JTable
                        // Con "getInt" y "getString" obtenemos los valores de las diferentes columnas pasandole el número de columna
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{
                                        Integer.toString(rs.getInt(1)),
                                        rs.getString(2),
                                        rs.getString(3),
                                        rs.getString(4),
                                        rs.getString(5),
                                        Integer.toString(rs.getInt(6)),
                                        Double.toString(rs.getDouble(7))
                                            });
                                        }

                    // Cerramos las conexiones, en orden inverso a su apertura
                    conn.close();
                    rs.close();
                    st.close();
                } catch (SQLException error) {
                    System.out.println("Error!, no se pudo llenar el JTable.\n" + error);;
                }
```

No tengo idea de el por qué dice que la conexión se ha cerrado si estoy solicitando una nueva conexión. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias por todo y por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que si hay una excepción antes, los `close()` no se ejecutan.

Normalmente se ciera en el `finally` del `try-catch`, para asegurarse de que se cierre aunque se lance una excepción.

Además, no está de más cerrar en orden inverso (primero rs, luego st, luego conn).

Asegúrate de que no lance excepción al cerrar. Sería improbable, pero confundiría bastante.

```
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    ...
  } finally {
    try {
      rs.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // LOG
    }

    try {
      st.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // LOG
    }

    try {
      conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // LOG
    }
```

Si usas Java 7 o posterior, puedes usar el try-with-resources, que ya se encarga de cerrar al salir del `try`

```
try (Connection conn = crearConexion();
     Statement st = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(showTableSQL);) {
    ... Leer resultset
} catch (SQLException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, dejame preguntarte algo, he hecho lo que me dijiste pero, en rs, st y conn me marca error diciendo: cannot be resolved, create local variable. Por qué?. Soy nuevo en MySQL, estoy aprendiendo, espero puedas ayudarme. Por qué pide esto si tengo las variables creadas mas arriba?. Screenshot del codigo: http://oi67.tinypic.com/10r4960.jpg

Comment: Las variables definidas dentro de un bloque (por ejemplo el `try`) no son visibles fuera de ese bloque (el bloque del `try` acaba en al cerrar llaves en el primer `} catch (...) {`). Define las variables **fuera** (delante) del `try` (pero sólo asígnales `null` porque sino te arriesgas a una excepción fuera del `try`). Es decir, `Connection conn = null; Statement st = null; ResultSet rs = null; try { ... //Obtener conexión, statement y resultSet`

Comment: muchas gracias, todo perfecto ahora!..