# Posibles problemas de un bucle infinito en las conexiones con Base de Datos

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un bucle infinito en el cual  mando a llamar un método que va hacer una tarea programada de modificar datos en mi BD. el bucle se ejecuta al arrancar mi programa.

mi duda es si es que esto del bucle infinito no me traería problemas o deficiencias en las conexiones con mi BD.

```
  import java.sql.*;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Date;

/**
  *
  * @author bitPanG98
  */
public class TareasProgramadas extends Thread {

public void run() {

    while (true) {

        try {

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            modificarEstadoReservacionPorExceso();

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

private void modificarEstadoReservacionPorExceso() {

    try {
        /*Ponemos el formato que va a tener la fecha*/
        SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        /*Obtenemos la fecha actual y la almacenamos en la varibale de tipo Date 'dateActual' */
        Date dateActual = FechaHora.obtenerFechaActual();
        /*Declaramos una variable de  tipo String el cual Obtenemos la fecha actual pasandole el formato de fecha */
        String fechaActualFormateada = formatoFecha.format(dateActual);

        String consultaCargarDatos = " SELECT r.codigo_reservacion , m.numero_mesa "
                + " FROM reservacion r , mesas m , detalle_reservacion dr "
                + " WHERE dr.codigo_reservacion=r.codigo_reservacion AND dr.numero_mesa = m.numero_mesa AND r.estado='Activa' AND r.fecha_reservacion = CURDATE() AND r.hora_maximaespera <= curTime() ";

        Connection con = new ConexionBD().conectarBD();
        Statement sta = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(consultaCargarDatos);

        while (rs.next()) {

            String codigoReservacion = rs.getString("codigo_reservacion");
            String numeroMesa = rs.getString("numero_mesa");

            System.out.println("resultados de las reservaciones   codigoR :  " + codigoReservacion + " .... numero mesa : " + numeroMesa);
            String consultaModificarReservacion = " UPDATE reservacion r, mesas m SET r.estado ='Inabilitada' , m.estado ='Libre' WHERE   r.codigo_reservacion= '" + codigoReservacion + "' AND m.numero_mesa='" + numeroMesa + "' ";

            Statement sentencia = con.createStatement();
            int respuesta = sentencia.executeUpdate(consultaModificarReservacion);
            if (respuesta > 0) {
                System.out.println("se ejecuto la consulta de modificacion");
            } else {
                System.out.println("no se ejeuto la consulta");
            }

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

  }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo escoger un mejor titulo, recuerda que otros usuarios hacen busquedas de acuerdo al titulo, y el tuyo es muy vago.

Comment: Vas a tener problemas si no cierras tus statements y la conexión a la base de datos. Pero si ya lo hacés no debería haber ningún drama. Te recomiendo utilizar un try-catch-finally y en éste último cerrar las conexiones. Si no sabes como hacerlo dime y te dejo un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que se sature tu espacio de memoria y la coneccion con la BD, te recomiendo cierres tu objeto `con` y el objeto `sta`

```
con.close();
sta.close();
```

Te recomendaria que los cerraras con la sentencia try-catch-finally de la siguiente manera.

`try{
    ...
}catch(SQLException ex){
    ...
}finally{
    con.close();
    sta.close();
}`

Si gustas algo mas de información te invito a que veas la documentación oficial [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) o que le des una visita a este post [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36080/como-cerrar-la-conexion-correctamente-con-mysql-en-java-al-leer-desde-la-base-de).